# How to fix aspell (bn-BD) invalid strings compiling issue

Tags: dictionary, language, aspell

When I tried to re-create `aspell-bn` (bn-BD) i.e. of Bengali(BD) language spellchecker with help of this [link](http://blog-archive.copyninja.info/2011/05/tutorial-creating-aspell-dictionaries.html) for aspell6 by compiling like the following

```
$ cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@cvs.savannah.gnu.org:/sources/aspell co aspell-lang

$ cd aspell-lang

$ ./pre bn u-beng

$ cd bn

$ ./proc create
```

This creates configure script and Makefile.pre and finally copying the word list file to working directory and named it as [bn.wl](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LknCOk0yT59rWIBf55mKD766gfkMxHlP) Word list file which contains list of words separated by new lines. And then

```
 $ ./configure
 $ make
```

(/usr/sbin/prezip-bin -d < bn.cwl | /usr/sbin/aspell  --lang=bn create master ./bn.rws)

But when I run "make", it prints many error messages and warnings like the following 2 types (The Unicode code points [**U+09CE**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A7%8E) and [**U+FEFF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) are unsupported), though according to [u-beng.txt](https://pastebin.com/qEwaBYby) **U+09CE** is clearly within the defined range.

```
Warning: The string "হৃৎযন্ত্র" is invalid. The Unicode code point U+09CE is unsupported. Skipping string.
Warning: The string "ক্ল্যারিজ" is invalid. The Unicode code point U+FEFF is unsupported. Skipping string.
```

After all of these, I do get a bn.rws file but it does not include all the words listed in bn.wl.

I am using parabola-arch x86-64

And `pacman -Qi aspell` returns

```
Name            : aspell
Version         : 0.60.6.1-5
Description     : A spell checker designed to eventually replace Ispell
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : http://aspell.net/
Licenses        : LGPL
Groups          : None
Provides        : None
Depends On      : gcc-libs  ncurses
Optional Deps   : perl: to import old dictionaries [installed]
```

If you can help me correct my mistakes then please. I am also including the [error.log](https://pastebin.com/AW224Ztr).

I guess I need to do something with the [u-beng.txt](https://pastebin.com/qEwaBYby) in the aspell-lang/maps folder or in the [u-beng.cset](https://pastebin.com/r8Za9fmt) & [u-beng.cmap](https://pastebin.com/EkPbYMn4) but I am not sure.

P.S. [Bengali_(Unicode_block)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_(Unicode_block))

And [Official Unicode Consortium code chart for Bengali.](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0980.pdf)

And [***a pull request.***](https://github.com/GNUAspell/aspell-lang/pull/2)